# Parsing xml using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I have a config XML which reads as -

```
<xml>
    <Section name="BackendStatus">
        <BEName BE="crust" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="pizza" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="pie" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="bread" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="Kulcha" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="kulfi" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="cheese" Status="1" />
    </Section>
</xml>
```

I need to parse each element in `BEName` to check Status. How can this be done using PowerShell?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

First step is to load your xml string into an XmlDocument, using powershell's
unique ability to cast strings to [xml]

```sh
$doc = [xml]@'
<xml>
    <Section name="BackendStatus">
        <BEName BE="crust" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="pizza" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="pie" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="bread" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="Kulcha" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="kulfi" Status="1" />
        <BEName BE="cheese" Status="1" />
    </Section>
</xml>
'@
```

Powershell makes it really easy to parse xml with the dot notation. This
statement will produce a sequence of XmlElements for your BEName elements:

```sh
$doc.xml.Section.BEName
```

Then you can pipe these objects into the where-object cmdlet to filter down the
results. You can use ? as a shortcut for where

```sh
$doc.xml.Section.BEName | ? { $_.Status -eq 1 }
```

The expression inside the braces will be evaluated for each XmlElement in the
pipeline, and only those that have a Status of 1 will be returned. The $_
operator refers to the current object in the pipeline (an XmlElement).

If you need to do something for every object in your pipeline, you can pipe the
objects into the foreach-object cmdlet, which executes a block for every object
in the pipeline. % is a shortcut for foreach:

```sh
$doc.xml.Section.BEName | ? { $_.Status -eq 1 } | % { $_.BE + " is delicious" }
```

Powershell is great at this stuff. It's really easy to assemble pipelines of
objects, filter pipelines, and do operations on each object in the pipeline.

Comment: Be aware that getting the tags via dot-walking will return null objects for any parent tags containing no children. E.g. `$doc.xml.Section.BEName.BEChild.Length` will be `7` for the above example, despite no BEChild tags being defined. This won't be an issue if you're filtering, but you will need to safely skip these null objects if you are iterating via `ForEach-Object` or similar.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to start with a file you can do this

```bash
[xml]$cn = Get-Content config.xml
$cn.xml.Section.BEName
```

[Use PowerShell to Parse an XML File](https://web.archive.org/web/20221005081256/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-parse-an-xml-file-and-sort-the-data/)

Comment: Link is broken :-(

Comment: fixed the link.

Comment: broken again - "The “Hey, Scripting Guys!” blog has been retired."

Answer (score 14):

```
[xml]$xmlfile = '<xml> <Section name="BackendStatus"> <BEName BE="crust" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="pizza" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="pie" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="bread" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="Kulcha" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="kulfi" Status="1" /> <BEName BE="cheese" Status="1" /> </Section> </xml>'

foreach ($bename in $xmlfile.xml.Section.BEName) {
    if($bename.Status -eq 1){
        #Do something
    }
}
```