# matching syntax issue

Tags: regex, xml, powershell

I am parsing a large XML file looking for certain content, e.g.

```psh
$matches = [regex]::matches($content, '(<ac:structured-macro.+?ac:name="jira".+?</ac:structured-macro>)'
```

i.e. return parts that start and end with the `<ac:structured-macro>` with "jira" in them.

What I am finding is finds other records as well, e.g.

```xml
<ac:structured-macro blah blah </ac:structured-macro>
<ac:structured-macro blah ac:name="jira" blah </ac:structured-macro>
```

I want it to find only the ones with "jira" in it.

1. How do I tell it that if you find the end "ac:structured-macro" and have not found the "jira" part to restart the search ?
2. Once I find this, I need to get parts inside this match. Is `.+?(item1).+?(item2)` the syntax? (similar to C#)

Source sample:

```xml
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,summary,type,created,updated,due,assignee,reporter,priority,status,resolution</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="server">JIRA (site.atlassian.net)</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">72f475d9-a9b2</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="jqlQuery">project = PLATFORM AND issuetype in (Bug, Question, Story) AND fixVersion = 1.12.1 AND component = &quot;UI Framework&quot;   </ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="maximumIssues">20</ac:parameter>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Comment: Please only use snippets for actual runnable javascript, css, or html.  They aren't meant for anything else.

Comment: NB: I should add that inside the structure are many other items, so the [^<]+? many not work ? e.g.

Comment: @GregBRoberts Edit the question to include the code; that aside, please stop adding thanks to the question; it distracts from the question and is not really something that is accepted around here.  Lastly, you can format code by adding four spaces before a block.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/184887) for more information regarding signatures/thanks/salutations.

Comment: Then I suggest casting to xml and parsing. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/18035655/5290909 ... If you insist with regex, to match nested elements, you have to use [balancing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments - don't use regex for XML!

Instead, use the built-in capabilities of .NET to parse it and work with it:

```
$XmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content .\largefile.xml)
```

Now, the $XmlDoc variable holds a live `XmlDocument` that we can inspect and modify programmatically (using `XPath`), instead of just plain text

From the contents of your brief snippets, I'm guessing that this large xml file is an XSLT template containing JIRA macro's for Confluence.

Since Confluence uses the namespace prefix `ac` - we'll need to create a namespace manager in order to query the document with `XPath`:

```
$XmlNSMgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $XsltDoc.NameTable
$XmlNSMgr.AddNamespace("xsl","http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform")
$XmlNSMgr.AddNamespace("ac","http://www.atlassian.com/schema/confluence/4/ac/")
```

Now you can select the desired nodes with the `SelectNodes()` method and an `XPath` expression:

```
$XPathExpression = '//ac:structured-macro'
$MacroNodes = $XmlDoc.SelectNodes($XPathExpression, $XmlNSMgr)
```

`$MacroNodes` is now a collection of all `<ac:structured-macro>` nodes found in the document.

To select only nodes where the `ac:name="jira"` attribute is present, add a clause to the `XPath` expression:

```
$XPathExpression = '//ac:structured-macro[@ac:name = "jira"]'
$JiraMacroNodes = $XmlDoc.SelectNodes($XPathExpression, $XmlNSMgr)
```

You can even edit nodes and the document will have been modified when you save edit:

```
$JiraMacroNodes |ForEach-Object {
    $_.SetAttribute("attrName","newValue")
}
$XmlDoc.Save("C:\path\to\new.xslt")
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias and mariano

Comment: Tried this but no finds. I think the issue is related to many of these macros being inside a ![CDATA ?  e.g.

<property name="body"><![CDATA[<p>This page lists the functionality release in version 1.12.0, and the component modules versions contained.</p><p><ac:structured-macro

# Running script on 2012R2 server 
# header of XML has no namespaces defined, just <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @GregBRoberts What do you mean "no hits"?

Comment: A break after the firest selectnodes shows no items selected. Having trouble formatting data in comments. I wanted to post more but system would not let me.

Comment: NB: Using $XPathExpression = '//object[@class="ReferralLink"]' resulted in many entries so the data is there, however I think the issue is the elements are inside [CDATA