# How to parse xml in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I have an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Node1 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Item Name="1" Value="value1" />
  <Item Name="2" Value="value2" />
</Node2>
```

I need to get both the name and value of the "Item"s inside the "Node1" node. I am trying the following and it doesn't seem to be working ($xml contains the above string):

```
Write-Host $xml.ChildNodes.Node1.ToString()
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing xml using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell)

Comment: FYI, your XML can't be parsed, as you have `<Node1>...</Node2>`. Change the `</Node2>` to `</Node1>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data type [XML] directly and with that you can parse, But it has to be a proper XML. Yours might need a little modification in the nodes. So that you can parse it using Dot :

**Example:**

```
$doc = [xml]
@'
<xml>
<Section name="Music">
<Song ="Love you" Status="1" />
<Song="Heartbeat" Status="1" />
<Song="Love to see you cry" Status="1" />
</Section>
</xml>
'@
```

Screenshot is for reference. 
[image]

Hope it helps.