# Powershell: using regex to retrieve substrings from text/file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a bunch of log files which should be parsed and some info from them - extracted.
A sample line (line that unfortunately, after trimming sensitive data looks like xml):

```
<SerialNumber>xxxxxxxxx</SerialNumber><IP>X.X.X.X</IP><UserID>user@domain.com</UserID><NumOfFiles>1</NumOfFiles><LocaleID>ENU</LocaleID><Vendor>POLYCOM</Vendor><Model>VVX311</Model><Revision>Rev-A</Revision><CurrentTime>2018-03-12T02:42:59</CurrentTime><CurrentModule><FileName>cpe.nbt</FileName><FileVersion>
```

I want to get ip ( in ip tags), and usermail (between userid tags)

My current "solver"

```
$regex = "<UserID>"

$files = Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\path\*.log'
foreach ($infile in $files) {
$res = select-string -Path $infile -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  {
$txt = $res[$res.count-1]

# get user
$pos1= $txt.line.IndexOf("<UserID>")
$pos2= $txt.line.IndexOf("</UserID>")
$Puser = $txt.Line.Substring($pos1+8,$pos2-$pos1-8)

....
}
```

it works, but I wonder if different approach will be better, want see how this could be done with 
select-string -pattern ...

Tried several "GUI" regex builders, but I can't figure how to select whats needed
Thanks

PS:

Result after

```
$regex = '<IP>(.*)</IP>'
$res = select-string -Path $infile -Pattern $regex
$res

0312092535|cfg  |4|00|DevUpdt|[LyncDeviceUpdateC::prepareAndSendRequest] '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Request><DeviceType>3PIP</DeviceType><MacAddress>11-11-11-11-11-11</MacAddress><SerialNumber>111111111111</SerialNumber><IP>10.1.1.1</IP><UserID>user@domain.com</UserID><NumOfFiles>1</NumOfFiles><LocaleID>ENU</LocaleID><Vendor>POLYCOM</Vendor><Model>VVX311</Model><Revision>Rev-A</Revision><CurrentTime>2018-03-12T09:25:35</CurrentTime><CurrentModule><FileName>cpe.nbt</FileName><FileVersion><Major>5</Major><M
```

Sample of log file (100Kb+)

```
0312104211|nisvc|2|00|Invoker's nCommands,CurrentKey:2,(106)Responder
0312104211|nisvc|2|00|Response(-1)nisvc,(-1),(-1)app,(22),(Expiry,TransactionId,Time,Type):(-1,-1,1520844131,1)IndicationCode:(400)
0312104211|app1 |5|00|[CWPADServiceEwsRsp::execute] PAC file failed with ''
0312104301|cfg  |4|00|DevUpdt|[LyncDeviceUpdateC::prepareAndSendRequest] '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Request><DeviceType>3PIP</DeviceType><MacAddress>11-11-11-11-11-11</MacAddress><SerialNumber>64167F2A8451</SerialNumber><IP>10.1.1.1</IP><UserID>user@domain.com</UserID><NumOfFiles>1</NumOfFiles><LocaleID>ENU</LocaleID><Vendor>POLYCOM</Vendor><Model>VVX311</Model><Revision>Rev-A</Revision><CurrentTime>2018-03-12T10:43:00</CurrentTime><CurrentModule><FileName>cpe.nbt</FileName><FileVersion><Major>5</Major><Minor>
0312104301|nisvc|2|00|Request(-1)nisvc,(701)NIServiceHttpReqMsgKey,(-1)proxy,(1001)AuthRsp,(Expiry,TransactionId,Time,Type):(45000,1306758696,1520844181,0)IndicationLevel:(200)
```

Comment: Why are you parsing xml....

Comment: Duplicate of [Parsing xml using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell)

Comment: If the XML is all in one line, the Regex should be pretty straighforward, something like `<IP>(.*)</IP>.*<UserID>(.*)<UserID>`. It is far more easy using XML existing classes to get info from XML data ;-)

Comment: The file is NOT xml file, its a log file with "xml-like" lines here and there. Sample line means just a sample - of thousands lines in the log file I pasted the one line that contains the info.

And question is how to extract (if possible) values using 
Select-string -Pattern

As i already wrote - I did solve the task in a different way

Comment: Updated 1st post: adding full sample of log file and current result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get all the files, read each file line by line and create objects with a user and ip and put them in an array.

```
[regex]$ipUserReg = '(?<=<IP>)(.*)(?:<\/IP><UserID>)(.*)(?=<\/UserID>)'
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -filter *.log
$users = @(
    foreach ($fileToSearch in $files) {
        $file = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fileToSearch)
        while (!$file.EndOfStream) {
            $text = $file.ReadLine()
            if ($ipUserReg.Matches($text).Success -or $userReg.Matches($text).Success) {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    IP = $ipUserReg.Matches($text).Groups[1].Value
                    User = $ipUserReg.Matches($text).Groups[2].Value
                }
            }
        }
        $file.Close()
})
```

To build out my regex, I often use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com), but keep in mind powershell is slightly different when it comes to certain regex.

**Edit:** Here is an example using select-string rather than reading line by line:

```
[regex]$ipUserReg = '(?<=<IP>)(.*)(?:<\/IP><UserID>)(.*)(?=<\/UserID>)'
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -filter *.log
$users = @(
    foreach ($fileToSearch in $files) {
        Select-String -Path $fileToSearch.FullName -Pattern $ipUserReg -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {
            $_.Matches | ForEach-Object{
                New-Object psobject -property @{
                    IP = $_.Groups[1].Value
                    User = $_.Groups[2].Value
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Am I right that everywhere in text the regex variable is $ipUserReg?  

Here and there its used as $ipReg or $userReg 0-o
  
Works fine, 1 problem - this way the program runs almost 10x slower :O  
    regex usage  
    execution time  24.0324853  
    Total files: 0 Total bytes: 59713119  
    "old style"  
    execution time  2.0694602  
    Total files: 239 Total bytes: 59713119       
"Old style" refers to using $txt.line.IndexOf to find positions of <ip> and </ip> the extract with $txt.Line.Substring, then same for the user

Comment: Damn, I can't format my answer :(

or editor has problems with Chrome?!
Either way, it works 10x slower than using .IndexOf to find substring position and then Substring to extract Ip/User :(      
    
also can't mark your answer as correct :S

Comment: @ChavdarChavdarov Added another example with `select-string`

Comment: @ChavdarChavdarov Make sure to mark the answer to help others that find this thread

Comment: Thanks, finally found where is "mark as answer" :D
I think the bulk of speed difference was due to reading line by line 
:)