# Powershell regex to get string between string and char

Tags: powershell, regex-greedy

I have file with some variables in it like this:

```
${variable}
```

And i want to loop through file and output:

```
variable
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

etc.

My code:

```
function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $importPath){

    #Get content from file
    $file = Get-Content $importPath

    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

    #Perform the opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

    #Return result
    return $result

}

GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "\\${" -secondString "}" -importPath ".\start.template"
```

## EXAMPLE of input file line:

```
<input id="paymentMethod_VISA" type="radio" name="${input.cardType}" value="VISA" checked="checked" style="width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;"/>
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to determine the usefulness of this function. Normally, matching a pattern already takes place between strings (a string is just an array of chars).

Comment: yes, but this is not the point of the problem at all. I am just not able to take "variable" from that 'pattern'

Comment: you mean Get-Content $importPath | ? {  string object -match "\\${(.*?)}" }

Comment: I've tried this Get-Content ".\vocGB_start.template" | ? {$_ -match "`${(.*?)}" } but with empty result

Comment: Can you post what is in your file?

Comment: See example input

Comment: So out of that whole line, you want to capture `${input.cardType}` or `input.cardType`? It looks like you want `input.cardType`. Just trying to verify before I go to work on it some more.

Comment: Is the input file in certain format e.g. xml/json file?  If yes, maybe it would be easier to read it and parse it via specialized parsing e.g. xml parsing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $importPath){
    #Get content from file
    $file = Get-Content $importPath -Raw

    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $regex = [regex] $('{0}(.*?){1}' -f [Regex]::Escape($firstString), [Regex]::Escape($secondString))

    $result = @()
    #Perform and return the result
    $match = $regex.Match($file)
    while ($match.Success) {
        $result += $match.Groups[1].Value
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    }
    return $result
}
```

and call te function:

```
GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString '${' -secondString '}' -importPath '<PATH_TO_YOUR_INPUT_FILE>'
```

Because the function now takes care of escaping the strings give in `$firstString` and `$secondString`, you don't have to bother about this when calling the function.
Also, because there may be more matches in the input file, the function now returns an array of matches.

i.e. if your input file contains stuff like this:

```
<input id="paymentMethod_VISA" type="radio" name="${input.cardType}" value="VISA" checked="checked" style="width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;"/>
<input id="paymentMethod_OTHER" type="radio" name="${input.otherType}" value="Other" checked="checked" style="width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;"/>
```

the returned matches will be

```
input.cardType
input.otherType
```

Comment: @MartinFric You're welcome! By the way, It is better to rename the function to `Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings` so it complies with the Powershell naming convention for functions and cmdlets. You can read about that [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/learning-powershell-names?view=powershell-6#cmdlets-use-verb-noun-names-to-reduce-command-memorization) or [there](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands). Especially when you are making a module and do not want PS to complain..

Answer (score 1):

I've provided alternative implementation to the one @Theo proposed:

Script:

```
$path = ".\file.txt"
$content = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw
$m = $content | Select-String -pattern '\${(?<variable>[^}]+)}' -AllMatches
$m.matches.groups | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "variable"} | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.Value}
```

Input file:

`<input id="paymentMethod_VISA" type="radio" name="${input.cardType}" value="VISA" checked="checked" style="width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;"/>
<input id="${input.second}" type="${input.third};"/>`

Output:

```
input.cardType
input.second
input.third
```