# How to pull some text from txt file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parsing, text, split

I have the text below and want to pull some data from it:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Title
4. Department
5. Division
6. Mobile
7. IP Phone Extension
8. Direct Manager

```xml
<UserInputs>
    <UserInput Question="Service Type" Answer="User Account Management" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account Management" Answer="New User Account" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - First Name " Answer="John" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Last Name" Answer="Snow" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Title" Answer="Officer" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Department" Answer="IT" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Division" Answer="Infratructure" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Mobile" Answer="+962799999993" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - IP Phone Extension" Answer="8879" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Direct Manager" Answer="&lt;Values Count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Value DisplayName=&quot;Jack&quot; Id=&quot;8c75d26a-2eaf-7e45-9139-178b88c42d6d&quot;/&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;" Type="System.SupportingItem.PortalControl.InstancePicker" />
    <UserInput Question="Urgency" Answer="b02d9277-a9fe-86f1-e95e-0ba8cd4fd075" Type="enum" />
</UserInputs>
```

I have tried something like `split` but it does not work (get some values as `Null`) can you please help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and we're happy to help you to make it work.

Comment: Please do some research on extracting data from XML with PowerShell. Questions about this have been asked (and answered) before. Also, for help with your code: show your code. Show the expected and actual result too. Do not paraphrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing xml using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell)

Comment: Do you want to pull data from the **text** file or the **HTML** file???

Comment: Thank you for Commenting Guys.
check my resolution Below and Theo's Answer also Worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Powershells XML capability for this

Read in the text file with `[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path '<Path to the xml file>' -Raw`
Here I have faked that using a 'here-string'

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<UserInputs>
    <UserInput Question="Service Type" Answer="User Account Management" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account Management" Answer="New User Account" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - First Name " Answer="John" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Last Name" Answer="Snow" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Title" Answer="Officer" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Department" Answer="IT" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Division" Answer="Infratructure" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Mobile" Answer="+962799999993" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - IP Phone Extension" Answer="8879" Type="string" />
    <UserInput Question="User Account - Direct Manager" Answer="&lt;Values Count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Value DisplayName=&quot;Jack&quot; Id=&quot;8c75d26a-2eaf-7e45-9139-178b88c42d6d&quot;/&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;" Type="System.SupportingItem.PortalControl.InstancePicker" />
    <UserInput Question="Urgency" Answer="b02d9277-a9fe-86f1-e95e-0ba8cd4fd075" Type="enum" />
</UserInputs>
"@

# The 'Direct Manager' has two properties we need to filter out.
$manager = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | ? { $_.Question -match 'Direct Manager\s*$' }).Answer
$managerName = $managerId = 'Unknown'
if ($manager -match 'DisplayName=(?:&quot;|")(?<name>[^&"]+).+Id=(?:&quot;|")(?<id>[^&"]+)') {
    $managerName = $matches['name']
    $managerId   = $matches['id']
}

# Create an object of the info for output
[PSCustomObject]@{
    'First tName'         = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'First Name\s*$' }).Answer
    'Last Name'           = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'Last Name\s*$' }).Answer
    'Title'               = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'Title\s*$' }).Answer
    'Department'          = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'Department\s*$' }).Answer
    'Division'            = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'Division\s*$' }).Answer
    'Mobile'              = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'Mobile\s*$' }).Answer
    'IP Phone Extension'  = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -match 'IP Phone Extension\s*$' }).Answer
    'Direct Manager Name' = $managerName
    'Direct Manager Id'   = $managerId
}
```

This will yield:

```
First Name          : John
Last Name           : Snow
Title               : Officer
Department          : IT
Division            : Infratructure
Mobile              : +962799999993
IP Phone Extension  : 8879
Direct Manager Name : Jack
Direct Manager Id   : 8c75d26a-2eaf-7e45-9139-178b88c42d6d
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I Did resolve it in another way but you did it better you know,
You Can Check My Code Down below.
Yes it is Simple, But worked :D.

Answer (score 0):

I Did Resolved As Below:

```
clear-host
$content = Get-Content D:\Temp.txt | Out-String
$content = $content -split "/><"

$FirstN = [regex]::match($content[2],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$LastN  = [regex]::match($content[3],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Title  = [regex]::match($content[4],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Dep    = [regex]::match($content[5],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Div    = [regex]::match($content[6],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Mobile = [regex]::match($content[7],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Phone  = [regex]::match($content[8],'Answer="([^/)]+)" Type=').Groups[1].Value
$Manager= [regex]::match($content[9],'DisplayName=&quot;([^/)]+)&quot; Id=&quot;').Groups[1].Value

$properties =@{
'First Name' =$FirstN
'Last Name'  =$LastN 
'Title'      =$Title 
'Department' =$Dep   
'Division'   =$Div   
'Mobile'     =$Mobile
'IP Phone'   =$Phone 
'Manager'    =$Manager
}
```

Comment: Just a little tip: You don't need to do `Get-Content D:\Temp.txt | Out-String` to get the content into a single string. Just add the `-Raw` parameter to `Get-Content`. Otherwise: looks ok to me ;)

Comment: @Theo In PowerShell v2 and earlier you do.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sure, to split the manager name and id properties from the `Direct Manager` value, it would also have been possible to use something like this: `$manager = ($xml.UserInputs.UserInput  | Where-Object { $_.Question -like '*Direct Manager*' }).Answer ; $managerName = ($manager | Select-Xml -XPath 'Values/Value/@DisplayName').ToString() ; $managerId   = ($manager | Select-Xml -XPath 'Values/Value/@Id').ToString()`, but in this case I found it easier to use a simple regex.

Comment: It is no a real xml file, it is the output of SCSM USER INPUTS for a service request.