# PowerShell: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument"

Tags: xml, powershell

I am following along the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell) on how to parse XML with Powershell. I copied the contents of the example XML text and tried to parse with given commands. Everything worked OK.

Then I tried to parse my own XML file but immediately after I had issued  `[xml]$bar = Get-Content test2.xml` command, I got the following error:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0
x3D, cannot be included in a name. Line 5, position 19."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]$bar = Get-Content test2.xml
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

So I suppose the mere fact that the contents of the XML file differ affects Powershell's ability to parse XML data?

My XML file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<metamarket id="lowvol">
    <market id="asx" marketDir="creditcentraligaapaclve_asx_m" mandatoryNews="False">
        <houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE" metahouseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"/>
    </market>

    <market id="bru" marketDir="creditcentraligaapaclve_bru_m" mandatoryNews="False">
        <houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE" metahouseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"/>
    </market>

    <market id="sto" marketDir="creditcentraligaapaclve_sto_m" mandatoryNews="False">
        <houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE" metahouseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"/>
    </market>
</metamarket>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates the source of the problem, though it doesn't specifically indicate that an *element* name is the problem (emphasis added):

> Error: "The **'=' character**, hexadecimal value 0
>   x3D, **cannot be included in a *name***. Line 5, position 19."

Element names (node names in general) in XML cannot themselves contain `=` characters.

By contrast, the `=` in tokens such as `id="lowvol"` is a *separator* between an attribute name and its value.

Your XML mistakenly uses such a token - `houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"` - *directly after an opening tag's `<`*, so that `houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"` was interpreted as the *element name*.

The solution is to give your element a proper name, such as `house`:

```
<house houseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE" metahouseCode="CREDITBAAPACLVE"/>
```