# PowerShell parsing XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I’m writing script in PowerShell parsing xml file and I’m stuck in.
XML file looks like:

```xml
Root:
<wnio:Dokument xmlns:adr="http://
```

and

```xml
<wnio:TrescDokumentu format="text/xml" kodowanie="XML">
    <str:Zalaczniki>    
    <str:Zalacznik format="application/octet-stream" kodowanie="base64" 
    nazwaPliku="1274964.pdf.xades">
```

piece of my code:

```bsh
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/wnio:Dokument/wnio:TrescDokumentu/str.Zalaczniki/str.Zalacznik")
```

and PowerShell throws out error:

```
Exception calling "SelectNodes" with "1" argument(s): "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function"
        At D:\Users\piotrek\Documents\Powershell\XML\dekoduj_xml_2.ps1:7 char:1
        + $nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/wnio:Dokument/wnio:TrescDokumentu/str.Z 
        + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

so, I tried:

```bsh
        [System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $file = resolve-path("D:\XML\ps3\dokument_68498452_tmp.xml")
        $xd.load($file)
        nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager($xd.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"); 
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
```

and I got:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace : The term 'nsmgr.AddNamespace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nsmgr.AddNamespace:String) [],
    CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
     
nsmgr : The term 'nsmgr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager($xd.NameTable);
    + ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nsmgr:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
     
nsmgr.AddNamespace : The term 'nsmgr.AddNamespace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nsmgr.AddNamespace:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don’t know what to do.
Please help!

Comment: What is your end goal? What specifically are you trying to parse out of the xml? And the xml looks a bit odd to me, are you missing some of it in the question?

Comment: The `nsmgr` should be a variable, `$nsmgr`.

Comment: Your xml is not valid.  The namespace "wnio" is not defined.

Comment: See if the below link is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell