PowerShell CMD to read XML data element
my XML
<application-set>
    <application application-containing-files="true">
        <application-information>
            <application-number application-type="**fdaat4**">**123456**</application-number>
        </application-information>
        <submission-information>
            <submission-id submission-type="**fdast9**">0048</submission-id>
            <sequence-number submission-sub-type="**fdasst4**">**0053**</sequence-number>
            <form form-type="fdaft1"></form>
        </submission-information>
    </application>
</application-set>

I'm trying to read these value with Powershell
application-type (fdaat4) and its 'InnerText' value 123456
submission-type (fdast9) and its 'Innertext' value 0048
I spent so may hours with different tries and it is still hopeless.
*****update
I figured it out. The trick is to add the attribute name to the end of the [@attribute]."attribute-name'
$AppType = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//admin/application-set/application/application-information/application-number[@application-type]")."application-type"
$submisstiontype = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//admin/application-set/application/submission-information/submission-id[@submission-type]")."submission-type"
*******************end update
Thanks

Please [edit] the question and add the code that you tried into it. Without that you may not get much help. Also please see [ask].

Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032147/parsing-xml-using-powershell

You might be able to use XPath to get the nodes of interest, looks like the nodes you're looking for have a name ending with -number or -id in which case you could use the following:
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load('path\to\xmlfile.xml')
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[contains(name(), '-number') or contains(name(), '-id')]")
$nodes | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        NodeName       = $_.Name
        AttributeName  = $_.Attributes.Name
        AttributeValue = $_.Attributes.Value
        Value          = $_.InnerText
    }
}

With the provided XML in question, the above will result in this array of objects:
NodeName           AttributeName       AttributeValue Value
--------           -------------       -------------- -----
application-number application-type    **fdaat4**     **123456**
submission-id      submission-type     **fdast9**     0048
sequence-number    submission-sub-type **fdasst4**    **0053**


Thanks. This will list everything but I need to capture the exact element or attribute

This will return those 4x strings:
$xmlFilePath = 'C:\test.xml'
$xmlFile = [xml]::new()
$xmlFile.Load($xmlFilePath)

# **fdaat4**
$xmlFile.'application-set'.application.'application-information'.'application-number'.'application-type'

# **123456**
$xmlFile.'application-set'.application.'application-information'.'application-number'.'#text'

# **fdast9**
$xmlFile.'application-set'.application.'submission-information'.'submission-id'.'submission-type'

# 0048
$xmlFile.'application-set'.application.'submission-information'.'submission-id'.'#text'

Lee Holmes made a useful GUI tool called Show-Object that's like a recursive Get-Member; it can help you quickly drill down into objects.  Running $xmlFile | Show-Object will help you find methods and properties for working with XML files.
Show-Object
See also: Spelunking With Show-Object

I found similar codes somewhere but I don't know why the dot thing didn't work with my script. I have to use \
